# Multiple inheritance in variadic template class & calling constructors

Tags: c++, class, templates, variadic

Let's say I have this example:

```
//Two interfaces
class InterfaceA {
public:
    InterfaceA(int val);
};

class InterfaceB {
public:
    InterfaceB(int val);
};

//Class with multiple inheritance
template <typename... Intefaces>
class Base : public Interfaces... {
public:
    Base() : Interfaces(42) {}; // This is wrong
}
```

How to call constructors of the "Interfaces" classes with a single argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax is

```
Base() : Interfaces(42)... {}
```

Here `Interfaces(42)...` is a *pack expansion* with the pattern `Interfaces(42)`, which means that it expands to a list of tokens, one for each type in the pack, that resemble the pattern with `Interfaces` replaced with the  type.

See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for a more in-depth description.